# Prove series $\sum \frac{a_i}{1+|a_i|}$ converges

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

If $\sum_{i=1}^n a_i$ converges, does $\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{a_i}{1+|a_i|}$ always converge? If not, please give a counter-example. Thanks.

Comment: I think you meant $\sum_{i=1}^\infty$

Comment: @ThePortakal The problem is correctly posed as written. $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}$ convergence is just the problem of the convergence of $\sum_{i=1}^{n}$. It is, actually, more precise when posed the current way.

Comment: @ErickWong How does that method work if we do not know if $\sum a_n$ absolutely converges?

Comment: If $\{a_i\}$ is an alternating series https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_series_test, the answer is positive. So the counterexample should  not be an alternating series. Do you have an example that is conditional convergent but not an alternating series?

Comment: @JonathanDavidson Oops, my argument only worked if $|a_n|$ is monotone decreasing (but doesn't otherwise require $\sum|a_n|$ to converge) :).  Now I'm thinking that there may be a counterexample.

Comment: @C.Ding Just to clarify, do you mean "should not be an alternating series" or "should not satisfy the conditions of the alternating series test"?  I agree that a counterexample should not pass the alt. series test, but I'm less clear on more general alternating series (i.e. ones whose coefficients are non-monotonic).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a counterexample:

Let $c_n$ be a sequence of positive reals that converges slowly to $0$.  Consider the finite segment $S_n$ consisting of the $n+1$ $S_n := \{-c_n, \frac{c_n}{n}, \frac{c_n}{n}, \ldots, \frac{c_n}{n}\}$ summing to $0$.  If we concatenate these finite segments $S_n$ for $n=1$ to $\infty$, we get a series that converges to $0$, provided we ensure that $c_n \to 0$ so that partial sums actually tend to $0$ within each segment.  Other than this constraint we are free to choose $c_n$ arbitrarily.

Now let's look at the transformed form of $S_n$: the first term $-c_n$ maps to $-c_n/(1+c_n)$, and the other $n$ terms sum to $nc_n/(n+c_n)$.  These sum to $$ \frac{-c_n(n+c_n) + nc_n (1+c_n)}{(1+c_n)(n+c_n)} = \frac{(n-1)c_n^2}{(1+c_n)(n+c_n)} \sim c_n^2.$$

We can easily choose $c_n \to 0$ so that the sum of these diverges.  For instance $c_n = 1/\sqrt{n}$, or $c_n = 1/\log n$.

It looks like there's a lot of leeway to fiddle with this construction.  It doesn't appear critical to let the segment length grow to infinity, so maybe it can be simplified to a true alternating series.

Comment: Oh! Best counterexample! Sir, can you check my solution if it is ok to you!